# Modify profile on Azure AD B2C connected Angular app

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create a "User Preferences" page UI on my Angular app to allow the users to edit their data.

I understand that the user data is obtained from the token, they're called: claims

I'm using *Azure AD B2C* to authenticate them, i can see the user profile data but i can't modify the data.

So, i'm obtaining the user data through the claims on the token through this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.companyName = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount().idTokenClaims['extension_CompanyName'];
}
```

But i don't have any idea how to edit these claims, i don't encountered any information, only see that's is possible creating a new user flow for editing their data in Azure AD B2C, but the main idea is to stay in my app.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use a profile edit user flow
- Use the Graph API

Comment: Looking on some docs i found this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/working-with-b2c.md

Comment: It says "A user's B2C authentication cannot be used to authorize to AAD protected apps, or Microsoft APIs (which are also protected by AAD). As such, when you use MSAL.js, you cannot use the <your-tenant>.b2clogin.com/.../token endpoint to obtain a token for MS Graph API."

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations